# Global maximum and minimum of $\frac{(1-x^2)y}{1+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

> Let's consider $f:[-1,1]\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x,y):=\frac{(1-x^2)y}{1+x^2+y^2}$. Does $f$ attain its global maximum and minimum?

**My approach:**

If $x=1$, $x=-1$ or $y=0$ then we immediately see that those points can't be a maximum or minimum. So WLOG $x\neq1$, $x\neq-1$ and $y\neq0$. We see that

$$
\Big|\frac{(1-x^2)y}{1+x^2+y^2}\Big|\leq\frac{|y|}{1+y^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{|y|}+|y|}\leq \frac{1}{2}.
$$
So $f(0,1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(0,-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$ are the global maximum and minimum.

Can I do it like this if I want to avoid tedious calculation of partials and the first order condition?

Comment: Why did you deal with $x=\pm 1$ separately?

Comment: @jjagmath, I was a bit unsure but if I rethink it it should suffice if I only exclude $y=0$.

Comment: Looks right to me.